# How to access target DOM element within function scope when (this) has been binded to object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop, bind

I tried to search for awhile but really couldn't find anything. might not have been phrasing it properly but nonetheless here's a sample code below.

```
class MyClass {
   constructor(){
      this.list = $('li.someClass');
      this.runEvents();
   }

   runEvents() {
      this.list.on('mouseover', this.getSomeProperty.bind(this));
   }

   getSomeProperty() {
      // how do i get the specific element now that this points to the instance of MyClass?
       var attribute = $(this).data('someAttr');
   }
}
```

Hope the above makes sense. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Once the function has been bound, it's not possible to get its original `this` back inside the event handler. But you can examine the `event` parameter, and look to the `event.currentTarget` to get the element that triggered the listener:

```
getSomeProperty(event) {
  const list = event.currentTarget;
  const attribute = $(list).data('someAttr');
}
```

(The `.currentTarget` will also be the `.target` if the `li.someClass` is the innermost element element clicked on, but if it has a descendant, like a `<span>`, and the span is clicked on, the target will refer to the span, not the `li`. The `currentTarget` is more reliable since it refers to the element the listener is attached to, rather than the inner element the event was dispatched to.)

Comment: `originalTarget` has very poor browser support, currently it's only supported in Mozilla, `currentTarget` works well enough, just changed mouseover to mouseenter.

Comment: Oops, typo, you're right. I meant to refer to `currentTarget` there

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current event in `event.target`. And you do not need bind if you use lambda notation.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.list = $("li");
    this.runEvents();
  }

  runEvents() {
    this.list.on("mouseover", this.getSomeProperty);
  }

  getSomeProperty = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(this.list);
    console.log($(event.target).data("attr"));
  };
}
new MyClass();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Tests 1</li>
    <li>Tests 2</li>
</ul>
```